# how to enable the main body scroll when the height of a dialogue box is large in angular material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

In angular material i want to enable the main scroll when the content of dialogue is become larger. by default the background scroller is locked. i tried to enable it by changing overflow property of css but it doesn't work. is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Can you show an example or a demo in jsfiddle. If scroll is the issue then it can be fixed by adding overflow-y:scroll

Comment: i tried by using overflow-y:scroll but it works for the dialog box scroller not for the main body scroller. ok i m making a plunker of my problem & post it here. thnx for u response :)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZofKAxuDV11GgcUUVHpO?p=preview

Comment: Hi irin, Try removing the overflow-y:scroll and height:500px; from .md-primary

Answer (score 0):

Insert all content on

```
<md-content>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei.
</md-content>
```

And than

```
md-content {
overflow: auto;
}
```